# How do I align the cursor to the start of centred placeholder text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to align the cursor with my placeholder text but I can only align it at the start of the input box, the end, or in the middle, which ends up appearing in the middle of the text.

I tried text-indent, but once the viewport got to the smaller sizes, it all went to hell. I'd end up having to have like 50 media queries to have it all align.

Anyone got any solutions?

Comment: You want to put cursor in the end of placeholder content?

Comment: I mean if you focus the input, the cursor appears. But the placeholder disappears instead.